# How to use VueJS variable in Django if else tag?

Tags: django, vue.js

I want to use VueJS variable in Django `{% if %}` tag. My vue have `delimiters: ['${', '}']`. Exactly what I want to do is:

```
{% if django.variable == vue.variable %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You *cannot* do this. Django templates are evaluated server-side and do not have access to varialbes in JS which runs on the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your help.